# C++ Upsampling raw audio from 22050 to 48000 Hz

Tags: c++, windows, audio, sampling

I have raw audio data in the form of

```
vector<short> m_shorts;
```

The audio data is 22050 kHz mono.

Does anybody have any idea how I can (without any third party library) quickly convert the short vector to 48000 Hz mono?

I know it will not improve the sound. This is only for passing the audio data to an effect (which sounds better with higher sample rate).

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you want `44100Hz` (the double of `22050Hz`) or `48000Hz`? And `kHz` is very probably a typo, should be `Hz`

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Ah sorry, you are right. I think I would prefer 48000 Hz. But if 48000 is not easily possible, 44100 would also work.

Comment: Then please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Why don't you want to use external libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to double the sampling frequency from `22050Hz` to `44100Hz` (which is the double of 22050) you might do some [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation):

```
vector<short> m_shorts;
vector<short> outputs;
unsigned inplen = m_shorts.length();
output.resize(2*inplen+1);
for (unsigned ix = 0; ix < inplen; ix++) { // not sure of the bounds
  output[2*ix] = m_shorts[ix];
  output[2*ix+1] = (m_shorts[ix] + m_shorts[ix+1])/2;
}
```

But I am not an audio or signal processing expert. There could be more clever ways... (perhaps a [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) then an inverse Fourier).

And I am not sure that "would sounds better".

Comment: Linear interpolation works but it does not give a very good result. Ideally a proper resampling filter should be used.

Comment: This oversampling operation results in unwanted signal content in the range 11.025kHz to 22.05kHz that was not present in the original (known as aliasing or an image).   This is removed by a LPF in all practical up-sampling designs. The two-point interpolation uses here is an exceptionally crude LPF, which most likely has its cut-off frequency in the wrong place and a very wide stop-band.  The consequence is that large amounts of aliasing is occurring.  

You need a resampling filter with its knee frequency at 11.025kHz (or a little before) and a sharp roll-off.

Comment: Linear interpolation will probably work fine for things like speech, or if playing through a low quality device anyway.

Comment: @Marko Thank you for your comment. You don't have any sample code in C++, do you?

Comment: @tmighty It's years since I designed a digital filter, and it's not particularly easy to do from first principles.   I suggest having a look at open-source media players such as VLC, GStreamer et al for re-sampling code.

Comment: @Basile the size of the output is more precisely `2 * (inplen- 1) + 1`, and after the cycle the last element of the output should be filled with last element of the input.